# How to retrieve leads information in Web-hook using Test Form in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api

I have created a webhook using some samples. I am able to get leads information when using webhooks Test but not able to get the leads info using a Test form:
Steps I have followed:
1. Created a Facebook APP.
2. Added Facebook Login and leads_retrieval permission.
3. Subscribed my page
4. Created endpoints and Subscribed my App for leadgen

webhoook.php

```
<?php
// facebook variables 
$challenge = isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge']) ? $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'] : '';
$verify_token = isset($_REQUEST['hub_verify_token']) ? $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] : ''; 
$fb_access_token = "myaccesstoken";
// this is used to subscribe to facebook webhook
if ($verify_token === "abc123") 
{
echo $challenge;
}
// Process retrieved data from facebook webhook
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$leadgen_id = $data['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['leadgen_id']; // extract leadgen ID
error_log(print_r($leadgen_id, true));
?>
```

Output while testing from the App Webhook Dashboard:
[27-Feb-2019 09:09:50 Etc/GMT] 444444444444

But when I created a Test Form and trying from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing then it's not firing any event.
Output: failure         102 Server failure
My Test from has: Full name, email, Mobile No, State and city values

Comment: Ever solved the issue?